# How long I can legally stay in US with H4?

Tags: usa, h4-visa

My spouse has a US H1 visa stamped until 2018. I have the H4 stamped until 2018. I reached US recently and at the port of entry, the seal that was put says "admit until end September 2016".

Is it possible to extend my stay beyond September 2016? If yes, what is the procedure?

Comment: What does your husband's admission stamp say for "until"?

Comment: From a comment to the migrated question the OP says their I-94 says they were admitted until 2018. So I don't think the question is still relevant. To the OP: you can ask CBP to correct the stamp on your passport, if you want; but anyway it's the I-94 that is authoritative.

Comment: @phoog : My spouse's admission stamp says he is admitted until 2018. My I-94 says I am admitted until 2018 and as per my admission stamp it is September 2016.

Comment: @user102008 my understanding was that the visa is valid until 2018 but the admission stamp is until 2016.  This is admittedly based on the assumption that the OP is using the phrase "visa stamp" to refer to the machine readable sticker placed in the passport. This usage seems to be commonplace in certain circles, especially among H-1B workers.

Comment: @NeonGlow by I-94 do you mean your record in the database, which you looked up on the website?

Comment: @phoog: Yes the one that could be viewed and downloaded on-line. Appreciate the help.

Comment: @user102008 : I was referring to this seal which says "until 2016": Please see the image at http://blogs.usembassy.gov/philippines/length-of-stay-in-the-united-states/

Comment: @NeonGlow both of the dates on your stamp say 2016? The "until" date is supposed to match the I-94. It may just be that the border officer forgot to change the year on the date stamp.

Comment: @user102008 do you have a source that supports your assertion that the 1-94 is authoritative over the passport stamp?

Comment: @phoog: Yes. Both dates shows 2016. One is entry date and other is a date in September. May be I have to file an I-539 at USCIS to extend stay.

Comment: If the passport stamp shows 2016 in error, you should not have to pay to file I-539. To be clear, I think @user102008 is correct about the I-94 being authoritative; I am just asking for a reference because it would be helpful to have one.

Comment: @phoog: I am not sure about a reference. But it should be true simply because all the regulations regarding consequences of overstaying refer to the I-94, and not to a date next to the entry stamp. Also, passports can get lost, and the entry stamp with it, with no "replacement" of the entry stamp, so logically it cannot be authoritative if you cannot replace it; on the other hand, the I-94, if you get a paper one and lose it, can be replaced. Also, you can do Change of Status or Extension of Stay in the US, where you will get a new I-94, not an entry stamp.

Comment: @user102008 : Sounds logical. I-94 should be the authoritative document.